# How to determine Vue.js + Vuetify Component Size

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In a vue.js with vuetify SPA I would like to determine what is the maximum size that my webassembly application can occupy. I need to give exact width and height coordinates to the wasm app and I would like to embedd it between a v-toolbar and a v-footer.

I could get the overall window size and substract a hard coded value (compensating for the toolbar and the footer), but the most elegant solution would be to determine the maximum size available for the component.

1. Is there a way to do this?
2. Is there an event which would be fired by the framework if the dimentions change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an event that would be fired by Vue necessarily, but the [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) browser API might be useful to you. ([Here's](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver) a better explanation than the docs.) You can set it up to watch for the resize of your WASM app's containing element.